# Number of Invariant Subspaces .

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that matrix representation of a linear transform ( on a 2 dimensional vector space X = R^2 ) with respect to some coordinate axis is given as ( 0,0 ; 0,1 ) (rows) . How many subspaces are invariant under the transform ?

My attempt : Since the transformation matrix is given , let us assume it to be A . Hence Ax will be the transformation of x , where x belongs to the Vector space. Let x=  ( x1,x2) be a vector from X . Then Ax = (0,x2) . Which can be represented as 0 (x1,0) + 1(0,x2) . Hence the subspace with (0,1) as the basis will become my invariant subspace. But how can I calculate the number of such subspaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct, here is another way: the invariant subspace of $A$ is the set of $x$ such that $Ax=x$, which is also the kernel of $A-I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

$$A-I=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

whose kernel is clearly $\operatorname{span}([0,1])$, as you found.

This corresponds to one invariant subspace of dimension one.

I think the question of "count the numbers of invariant subspaces" is strange. Indeed, any singular linear operator has a unique *maximal* invariant subspace, so the answer could always be $1$ (even if it is of dimension $n$). Maybe the question should specify "count the numbers of one-dimensional invariant subspaces".

Comment: Hey, this is a general doubt on Invariant transforms: given a vector space M, and a Linear transform A. We Apple Ax on x , where x belongs to M . Is there any way in which we can make the coefficient matrix of the Linear transform as an a upper triangular matrix and then analyse any general problem of invariant subspaces.

Comment: @AnshumanSinha You might be interested in the [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).